# Can't replace an item inside of an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Wrighting an Angular application.

In this code I'm trying to replace an item at a specific number in array.

```
for (i=0;i<this.marked.length;i++) {
    this.index = this.marked[i].ind;
    this.newSongs[this.index] = this.marked[i].name;
}
```

This is what this.marked looks like:

```
{
    ind: index,
    name: songName
}
```

So why the result is this?

```
['name1', 2: 'name3']
```

instead of:

```
['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

Sorry, guys, it's actually this.marked[i].ind;
I deleted it accidentally. The problem isn't solved

Comment: i don't know if it was a typo from your question, weren't you supposed to write: `this.index = this.marked[i].ind` ? instead of `this.index = this.marked[i].` ? Not sure about the last dot ..

Comment: sorry, it's actually `this.marked[i].ind`
the problem is that index appears in my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Khalid and Joel gave you the right tip. You need to use:

```
this.index = this.marked[i].ind
```

Here's a angularJs fiddle for you. Hope this will help

https://jsfiddle.net/trollr/3adngkmx/

```
function SongCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.songs = [
        {
            ind: 1,
            name: "Tessie"
        },
        {
            ind: 2,
            name: "Kiss Me I’m Shitfaced"
        },
        {
            ind: 3,
            name: "The State of Massachusets"
        }
    ];

    $scope.replace = function(index, value) {
        for (i=0;i<$scope.songs.length;i++) {
            var currentIndex = $scope.songs[i].ind;
            if(currentIndex == index) {
                 $scope.songs[i].name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to replace

```
this.index = this.marked[i]
```

by

```
this.index = this.marked[i].ind
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I was trying to run my code inside of a loop. So when I pulled it out It worked correctly.